# how to use the system ("clear") function?

Tags: c

i am still on my journey of my game, i managed to improve many things.

Now in this new step, I am trying to use the clear function, but when I use it, it causes the random numbers to be generated when the user enters the answer.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main (){

    int i=0;
    int acertos =0;
    int numero;
    int resposta;

    printf("\n\nEste programa irá gerar numeros aleatorios para memorizar\n\n");
    printf("Pressione ENTER para jogar\n\n"); 
    {
        sleep(3);
    }

    do{
        printf("\n\n\nDecore os numeros: \n\n\n");
        for(i=0; i<10;i++){}
        printf("%d", numero);
        {
            sleep(3);
        }
    }while(i>10);

    system("clear"); 

    printf("\n\n\nInforme os numeros\n\n");

    for(i=0; i<10;i++){}

    printf("numero:");
    scanf("%d", &resposta);
    if(resposta==numero){
        acertos++;
        if(acertos==1){}
        printf("\nSua memoria esta TOP\n\n\t");
    }else
        printf("\n\nPoxa, melhor comer omega 3!Reveja:\n\n\t");
    for(i=0;i<10;i++);
    printf("%d\t", numero);
   
    return(0);
}
```

please help me to complete my journey in C language!

Comment: What's the purpose of `for(i=0; i<10;i++){}` and `if(acertos==1){}`?

Comment: It might help if you do `fflush(stdout);` just before `system("clear");`

Comment: You never initialize `numero`, so printing it will print garbage.

Comment: Your first `do-while` loop is an infinite loop, since `i > 10` is never true. You shouldn't ever get to `system("clear");`

Comment: why do you open `{}` before ever `sleep()` ?

Comment: Thank you @Craig Estey! you help me <3

Comment: Thank my friends, im young girl :P kkkkk kisses <3

Answer (score -1):

Let's clear some things out :

1- i see an issue here :

```
do{
    printf("\n\n\nDecore os numeros: \n\n\n");
    for(i=0; i<10;i++){}
    printf("%d", numero);
    {
        sleep(3);
    }
}while(i>10);
```

you started a `for` boucle then for the same objectif you did a `do{ }while();`
it's useless .

Secondly you started your `for` boucle then you closed it directly `{}`

to fix it :

```
printf("\n\n\nDecore os numeros: \n\n\n");
    for(i=0; i<10;i++) {
    printf("%d", numero);
        sleep(3);
    }
```

read more about [for loops](https://www.programiz.com/c-programming/c-for-loop)

2- i see in your code that you always open `{}` before every `sleep()` , it's useless  [you can check this](https://www.poftut.com/what-is-sleep-function-and-how-to-use-it-in-c-program/)

3- You have tried to print a variable that you never init it or used `scanf` in order to type a value
you can :

```
scanf("%d",&numero);
```

or :

```
int numero=0;
```

4- Finally im guessing you're trying to do an array here :

```
for(i=0; i<10;i++){
printf("numero:");
scanf("%d", &resposta);
```

read more about [Array of ints in c](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_arrays.htm)

so you're code becomes like this

```
int reposta[10];
for(i=0; i<10;i++){
printf("numero:");
scanf("%d", &resposta[i]);
```

I can't really fix your whole code as idk the objectif but i advice you to reread C basics . Thank you .

about your `system("clear")` it should be `system("cls")`